# Keycloak Change registration or activation flow

Tags: node.js, keycloak, registration, email-verification, keycloak-rest-api

I use this [Node.js library](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-admin-client) to register a user via `POST /{realm}/users`. That's working, but I have an issue with the user activation over an E-Mail. The scenario should be, that the user registers and **directly** gets an E-Mail with the **activation link** for his account. But this case is another in Keycloak. First you have to login with the new user once and after that you get the activation link and not right after the registration process. That's too late. So I trigger the API `PUT /{realm}/users/{id}/send-verify-email` to send the verification link as an E-Mail.
But the E-Mail text and template are another one. It's the same as from `PUT /{realm}/users/{id}/execute-actions-email`, which is confusing. It is also used for a update of user info etc. which is needed. So adjusting this E-Mail template isn't an option.

Is there a possibility in the Keycloak settings to send the correct E-Mail verification mail right after registering the user? Or can I add new E-Mail templates and assign them to the API?

I'm using the current version of Keycloak: 12.0.2